# firebase tools.firestore Unresolved variable firestore in cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image: img here]

i'm trying to delete a document that has a subcollation inside.
Does anyone have an idea why he does not recognize firestore?
thanks!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `firebase-tools` does not have such method.

`firestore` is part of `firebase-admin`. In the presented code it's imported to `admin` so to you should call `admin.firestore()...`.

BTW I have noticed that few lines above there is commented line where it is correctly called.